# Do I have to stop the react native server everytime I want to install a new node module

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules

React noobie here.
I have a question, I am working on a react native project, and I search for extensions I can add for my applications, whenever I want to install a new module, I have to stop the server and let the installation finish, then run the server again. This process takes too much time, is there a way I can circumvent that?

Comment: You could try this out and see. Starting the metro bundler is not very difficult or time consuming. You aren't installing modules every minute (or even hour) anyway.

And of course, native modules need the apps to be rebuilt.

Comment: If its just a javascript module, you could open a new terminal tab instead of stopping the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is good because the restart assures that all new files are added at the start of the app. I think it is a good thing even though it can be annoying but installing dependecies when the app is running would only make it harder to code imo.